# Data transformation - Python

Tags: python

I have the data in the following format (in a csv file):

```
a b c
b
a
a c d
b c
b c
```

I would like to covert the above data to the following format (list):

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b'],
 ['a'],
 ['a', 'c', 'd'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c']]
```

I have done this so far:

```
import csv

fileName = "toydataset.csv"

data = open(fileName, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
allRows
```

But, the output looks like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', '', ''],
 ['a', '', ''],
 ['a', 'c', 'd'],
 ['b', 'c', ''],
 ['b', 'c', '']]
```

How do I remove those null values from the list so the output looks like this?

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b'],
 ['a'],
 ['a', 'c', 'd'],
 ['b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [8]: l
Out[8]: 
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', '', ''],
 ['a', '', ''],
 ['a', 'c', 'd'],
 ['b', 'c', ''],
 ['b', 'c', '']]

In [9]: [ filter(None, a) for a in l]
Out[9]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b'], ['a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative.  If you're in to that sort of thing.

```
import csv


def clean_item(item):
    res = [x for x in item if x]
    return res


def main():
    # PEP-8!
    file_name = "toydataset.csv"
    with open(file_name, 'r') as data: # don't corrupt your data!
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        # PEP-8!
        all_rows = [row for row in reader if row]
        print(all_rows)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using any built-in method:

```
>>> l
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', '', ''], ['a', '', ''], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', ''], ['b', 'c', '']]
>>> [[i for i in j if i] for j in l]
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b'], ['a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```